# Can the name of a country always convey the name of a nation?

Tags: word-usage, toponyms

There is an old name of a country and its description:

> Persia: The **land** and **people** in southwestern Asia from the ancient Sassanian empire to the modern nation state of Iran, prior to 1935.

I found the description wrong grammatically because the name only refers to the land not people who are Persians/Iranians not Persia.

Is it correct to use the name of a country for the land and its people both in standard English?

P.S: It is the link: https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/416/some-mistakes-in-persias-tag-information and here: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persia but according to the link which has been sent by coleoptrist as a comment under this topic they have added something to the tag Persia recently so the content has changed!

Comment: I think you might need to re-word the question as it doesn't reflect the details you have provided (may be the reason for the down votes), as it is a valid question. In answer to your question I think that one is meant to guess that the people are **Persian**.

Comment: I guess they want to say that the term "Persia" refers both to the land (stones, mountains, rivers, etc.) and to the people.

Comment: @camden_kid Sorry I do not know what kind of change they need in question and by guess cannot change it.

Comment: @GEdgar I do not want to find what they want to say by this. I asked if it is correct or not and surely standard English is not working on guesses and imaginations or tastes. There are rules.

Comment: What about nomadic nation-peoples, like the Lapps?

Comment: [In your stated case](http://history.stackexchange.com/tags/persia/info), it is simply an error.

Comment: The name of a country represents not just the geographical boundary but it's citizens to. If one wants to refer solely to the people than one would say Persians.

Comment: @Robusto In that case the name refers solely to the people called Lapps. It doesn't represent any geographical limits

Comment: @coleopterist So do you mean it is grammatically wrong and this error has to be fixed or not? Your comment is not clear for me what you mean!

Comment: Yes, it is an error and if you like, you can look to get it fixed via [History meta](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RaduMiron: So how do we get Lapland?

Comment: @coleopterist Aha thanks! I found additional description is added to the previous one! And surly downvotes to my question about there! :)

Comment: @Robusto Of course they are related. All I said was that the name of a country stands for both it's land and people. In some cases the land was named after it's inhabitants in others the inhabitants were named after the land.

Comment: You're right, if you remove 'the land' you get "Persia: the people in ..." which is terribly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion stems from the fact that a "nation" is a rather amorphous thing.  I recall a Middle School geography lesson on Alexander the Great in which I asked what was meant when it was said that "He conquered the land from ... to ..."  Though my classmates laughed at me, I still think it is a valid question.  To be a part of a "nation" or a "country" or a "state" is not nearly as clear cut as it seems it should be; just ask the people of Alsace-Lorraine, Southern Morocco, Isreal-Palestine, or any number of other areas in conflict.

If you ask an Orthodox Jewish settler to define "Israel" you will get a very different answer than if you ask the same of a member of the Al Aqsa Brigades.  The same is true of the word "Persia."

Ultimately, however, terms like this don't mean anything if it isn't for the people.  While they are typically tied to a specific geographic area, when the people who live there no longer identify with that term, the "country" effectively ceases to exist.  We still use the term Persia because people who live there call themselves Persians.  We do not, however, use the term Harappan any longer because even though there are still people who live in Northern India, they no longer use that term to describe their land, people, and culture.

Answer (score 1):

*Metonymy* is the use of a figure of speech in which a thing or concept is not called by its own name, but by the name of something intimately associated with that thing or concept.

For instance, "Hollywood" is used as a metonym (an instance of metonymy) for the US cinema industry, because of the fame and cultural identity of Hollywood, a district of the city of Los Angeles, California, as the historical center of film studios and film stars. A building which houses the seat of government or the national capital is often used to represent the government of a country, such as "Westminster" (Parliament of the United Kingdom) or "Washington" (United States Government).

[[More from Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)

Thus this could be an example of metonymy: using "Persia" to refer to the people of the country. However, such a use would be clumsy; it appears that the quotation is from a dictionary definition which has been truncated for reasons of space and where *Persian* would normally be used to describe the nation itself.

Comment: I checked dictionaries and didn't find such a thing (it appears that the quotation is from a dictionary definition...) if not I didn't ask it.

Comment: I think it is akin to the Red Sox Nation. The collective fans of the Red Sox make up this nation; it goes beyond geographic boundaries.

Comment: Now I have to go and search what Red Sox is! :")